# styled-system Custom Breakpoints

Tags: styled-system

I would like to specify my own custom breakpints. The documentation as https://styled-system.com/responsive-styles/#using-objects only refers to `theme.js`.

But I don't understand where do I place `theme.js`? or find it? and how do I import it into the project? and how do I define breakpoints with aliases and use plain objects as values.?

Can someone please guide me? I am using `styled-system` in Gatsby.js

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to export a key called `breakpoints`. In my project we use a js file to define our theme, it looks like this

```
export const breakpoints = ['769px', '1367px'];
```

Since you are using Gatbsy, you need to install [gatsby-plugin-theme-ui](https://theme-ui.com/packages/gatsby-plugin/). Your theme file will be `src/gatsby-plugin-theme-ui/index.js`.

Comment: So what you are saying is to create a file `theme.js` which will contain this line of code you have mentioned. Now, where is the `theme.js` living?